# post-redirect-get and posting double entries into Database

Tags: php, post, redirect, get, double

I am currently doing a web application project for my final year in school. I am more of a web designer than a web developer so I need as much help as I can get!

For my project, I am create a website very similar to a blogging site.

The first function I wanted to implement runs when the user is registering, I wanted signUp.php(html form) / doSignUp.php(php post data to database) to prevent the user from using a username that is already in the database.

> For example, database has username="happy". User1 fill up the form at
>   signUp.php in the username fill "happy" and submit the form into
>   doSignUp.php. doSignUp.php checks the database whether
>   username="happy" is inside. If it is inside, it will NOT post the data
>   again inside to prevent double entry but instead REDIRECT back to
>   signUp.php and inform the user that with a message "the user name is
>   in used".

For the first function I have the idea of:

```
    $selectUser = executeSelectQuery("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username="$username")
if ($selectUser==0) {
    $doRegister = executeInsertQuery("INSERT INTO user (Name,Username, Email,
            Password, DOB_Date, DOB_Month, DOB_Year, Gender,admin, Country) VALUES
            ('$Name','$Username','$Email',SHA1('$Password'),'$DOB1','$DOB2','$DOB3','$Gender','$role' ,
            '$Country')");
} else {
<// redirect codes here to signUp.php with message "user name is in used">
}
```

Second function I want to implement involves login.php(login form), doLogin.php(check whether the posted data matches with the one entered in the login form) and memberPage.php(redirect the user to memberPage if he is the member and create a session for him, else redirect to login.php if he is not a member to show him some message).

As for the second function, I have really no idea how to implement the post-redirect-get method for my login. I tried google for demos to try but to no avail. Please help if you can! Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Code to redirect:

```
header("Location: signUp.php?message=" . urlencode("user name is in use"));
```

In signUp.php, to print the error, print `$_GET['message']`.

Comment: thanks for the help but I tried your code  header("Location: signUp.php?message=" . urlencode("user name is in use")); and it did not redirect when the user entered a used username, I cannot find what is wrong with it.

Comment: That's because your condition `if ($selectUser=0) {` is **always true** since you used assignment `=` instead of comparison `==` operator.

Comment: I changed mine to an == operator, I tested it. Even though my if condition is false, it does not redirect back to signUp page, but it prevented double entries now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, using the `header()` function to redirect back to your sign-up display page (signUp.php) with a message will work, however I often discourage this multi-file attempt at form processing.
Something much more appealing (at least to me) is placing the processing logic at the top of the file that displays the form. This logic would need to be wrapping in a check to make sure the form had been submitted. If anything goes wrong, it stores the error in a variable that could be displayed later in the file. Take a look at this example:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit') {
    if(!$userNameIsUnique) { //Mysql Processing - duplicate check here
        $message = "Username has already been used.";
    }
    //Check other fields for duplicates or invalid data
    if(!isset($message)) {
        //Form submit successful send info to data
        mail(); //Send confirmation email
        die('Check your email to verify your account!'); //Display success message
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>Signup</title></head>
<body>
    <?php if(isset($message)) echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>'; ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="username" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this situation, you can still separate views and controller logic (with file includes), but you avoid having two files and forcing two requests (one for the form submit and one to redirect back to the form) when there is an error with the input.

Comment: I would have use this code if I did not have email verification function etc. when the user successfully register. But thanks for the insight!

Comment: You can still use email verification with this. I'd create another file to link to from the email, but I'll update the code to show you where you could send the email from.